# Why does my command window present a Bus Error while passing a tag through?

Tags: c

I'm currently working on a school project where we are required to do some sequencing, but in my code however I am getting a `bus error` while running the double precision but not the single precision.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void singleprecision()
{
    float x[21];
    x[1] = 11.0f/2.0f; x[2] = 61.0f/11.0f;

    int k = 3;
    for (; k <= 10; k++)
    {
        x[k] = 111.0f-(1130.0f - 3000.0f/x[k-2])/x[k-1];
        printf("x[%d]:%f\n",k,x[k]);
    }
}



void doubleprecision()
{
    double x[21];
    x[1]=11.0/2.0;
    x[2] = 61.0/11.0;

    int k = 3;
    for(; k<=20; k++);
    {
        x[k] = 111.0 - (1130.0 - 30000.0/x[k-2])/x[k-1];
        printf("x[%d]:%lf\n",k,x[k]);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    int i = 0; // will there be double precision used based on the g input in the command line

    if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1],"-d")==0) // checking for -g input on the command line
    {
        doubleprecision();
        printf("Double Precision is being used \n");
    }
    else 
    {
       printf("Single Precision is being used \n");
       singleprecision();
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Any help would be wonderful in order to assist me in getting through this challenge and understanding it.

I am running on a remote linux system and compiling with gcc, it compiles fine but likewise fails when in double precision.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I edited you code to provide better indentation making it easier to read. Its best to get into the habit of indenting for the same reason! This will enable better responses.

Comment: In your for loop inside the `doubeplecision` function, you have a semi-colon at the end. If you turned on warnings with the `-Wall` flag in gcc you would see that warning. So, change: `for(; k<=20; k++);` to `for(; k<=20; k++)` by removing the semi-colon at the end.

Comment: @bruceg Actually, with _merely_ `-Wall`, `clang` produces the warning: _for loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]_. However, `gcc` produces: _warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]_. To get `gcc`, to do the same as `clang`, one must _explicitly_ specify `-Wempty-body`. That is, it is enabled by default in `clang` with `-Wall`, but _not_ in `gcc`. I had this issue with this a few years back, so now all my makefiles add the extra `-Wempty-body` by default. With `gcc`, doing `-Wall` and `-Wextra` also works.

Comment: BTW, it's conventional to put the loop variable in the `for()` header, e.g. `for(k = 3; i <= 20; k++)` rather than initialize it before the loop.

Comment: You might also have noticed this if you used a debugger. You would see that the `x[k]` assignment only runs once, and the value of `k` is `21`.

Comment: regarding: `if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1],"-d")==0) // checking for -g input on the command line`  The code is checking for `-d`,  but the comment says it is checking for `-g`..   Which do you actually want to check for?

Answer (score 1):

in the function: `doubleprecision()` remove the extraneous `;` from the end of the statement: `for(; k<=20; k++)`  Then the code runs with no problems.